# Annotation Validation Exception (com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I got following exception on IBM Websphere Application server 8.5 when I tried to deploy my application on server.
I'm using WS 8.5, EJB 3.1, Java EE 6 in my application.

```
[11/1/12 11:06:47:208 PKT] 0000005d annotations   E   CWWAM0003E: An exception occurred while validating an annotation: com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: CWWAM2302E: The class com.xxx.yyy.services.UsersServiceBean is annotated with an invalid @PersistenceContext declaration; no name is specified.
                             com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: CWWAM2302E: The class com.xxx.yyy.services.UsersServiceBean is annotated with an invalid @PersistenceContext declaration; no name is specified.
at com.ibm.ws.amm.validate.persistence.PersistenceContextValidator.validateClassAnnotation(PersistenceContextValidator.java:86)
```

Below is my Java code.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="myUnit")
@Stateless(name="UsersService")
public class UsersServiceBean implements UsersService {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, when declaring `@PersistenceUnit` on a class, you must add a `name="..."` that you can use to look up the `EntityManagerFactory` with `new InitialContext("java:...")`.  Alternatively, you can declare an `@PersistenceUnit(...) EntityManagerFactory emf;` field in your class and omit the name.

All ref annotations are basically the same as `@Resource`.  Per the commons annotations specification:

> The name element is the JNDI name of the resource. When the Resource
>   annotation is applied on a field, the default value of the name
>   element is the field name qualified by the class name. When applied on
>   a method, the default is the JavaBeans property name corresponding to
>   the method qualified by the class name. When applied on a class, there
>   is no default and the name MUST be specified.

The last sentence is relevant, and it makes sense: using `@PersistenceUnit` (and all other `@Resource`-like annotations) has two effects:

1. If you declare the annotation on a field or method, then the container will automatically inject when the instance is created.
2. The reference is inserted into the `java:comp` namespace using its name.  If you declare the annotation on a field or method, the default name is `java:comp/env/com.example.ClassName/targetName`.

If you declare the annotation on a class, then (1) there's no injection, and (2) there's no default name so there's no way to bind into `java:comp/env`.  In that case, the annotation declaration would be pointless, so it's an error.